# After 20+ years of lecturing, 3 masters (2 M.Sc.), at age of 54 years, is it feasible to start and finish a Ph.D., be hired as a Professor?

Tags: phd, professorship, age

After 20+ years of (part-time) lecturing, 3 masters (out of which 2 M.Sc.), at age of 54 years, is it feasible to start and finish a Ph.D. and be hired as a Professor?

Comment: This question has been asked many times before.  In short, you're never too old, but it's certainly true that you might have to deal with age based discrimination.

Comment: could you please clarify what type of career you hope to achieve?  A tenure-track research career? or a teaching faculty position? something else?  The answer depends on your specific goals.

Comment: At least the PhD part has been done before, for example by [Brian May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_May), who received his PhD in astrophysics at around 60 years old.

Comment: Suppose you start your PhD at 55 and you complete within X years. Further suppose you plan to retire at age Y. Thus, your question reduces to: after completing a PhD, can I be hired as a Professor in Y - X - 55 years?

Comment: Checkout the formal requirements at your actual goal. There might be a notion similar to "usual requirements (PhD, bla, bli, blup) might be not needed in case of extraordinary foo, fiz, baz of the candidate". It might be easier for you to show extraordinarity. Say, you have published 20 course books, but never formally bothered for a PhD. Or you have something named after you as a widely accepted notion.

Comment: @DanRomik - but Brian had basically done all but finishing the thesis. Plus the topic was a small enough niche that not much else had been done in the intervening decades so the thesis was still topical. Not a generally expected outcome...

Comment: @JonCuster well, Brian May’s case is unusual in other respects that are much more significant than the one you point out. For example, probably OP is not extremely rich and was not ranked among the top guitar players in the world by Rolling Stones and Guitar World magazines. So, possibly nothing useful can be learned from this example. Nonetheless, OP asked “is it feasible to [do X]?”, and since X is such an unusual thing to do, I don’t see a better way to meaningfully answer the question than to point the only examples I know of people who did X, or something that’s somewhat close to X.